# Wrapping columns in a table

Tags: html, css, asp-classic, styles

I have a table with a row that has 10 fixed width columns, what is the best way to adjust the table when re-sizing the page.

For example: if I resize the page and only 5 columns fit, how do I wrap the remaining 5 columns to a new row?

I'm looking for a pointer of what is the best way to do this.  Any suggestion will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I suggest not wrapping columns, since it makes tables very hard to read.

Comment: Can you post the relevant `HTML` structure you are using to better understand your goal? Also, Any relevant `CSS` will be useful to provide you with an accurate answer.

Comment: @Jim So, table may not be the best solution to this. What is the best way to display a list of fixed width image across a page that dynamically wraps when the page resizes.

Comment: One solution it to use javascript. when I calculate the width of the page and then send it back to the server to recalculate the # of images that can fit into each row. But I'm trying to avoid doing that.

Comment: If it's a list of images, then a list element, either `ul` or `ol` may be a better option for this type of layout.

Comment: @cchana thank, using a list now

Comment: @StevenWang use div, ul or ol with float CSS properties.

Comment: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ is always a fun solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reflow the cells I guess what you want is not really a table, just aligned elements.  For that, better use floats, like this...

```
<div style="overflow:auto">
    <div style="width:200px;float:left">A</div>
    <div style="width:200px;float:left">B</div>
    <div style="width:200px;float:left">C</div>
    <div style="width:200px;float:left">D</div>
    <div style="width:200px;float:left">E</div>
    <div style="width:200px;float:left">F</div>
    <div style="width:200px;float:left">G</div>
</div>
```

(better put the styling in the CSS file, use classes, etc. I used `div`s but same thing with styling `LI`s except maybe you need to add a `display:block` to the styling). Also, you might have to add a `height` too if the cells' contents can have different heights.

Comment: Add `overflow: auto` to the parent div and there is no need for an extra element with `clear: both` anymore.

Comment: I don't know, I just add it by default now. I sometimes get the next block to the right of it when I don't add the clear, even if the block is after the container `div`, not sure when it happens or why but I just solve it with a clear

Comment: Adding `overflow:auto` to the parent div solves this problem. `clear:both` could then be eliminated from your source, keeping it cleaner and more semantic. I leave it up to you ;)

Comment: changed, and thanks for the info, learn something new everyday